# inheritance with parent class specialization

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm sorry if I'm hard to understand, English is not my first language.

I'm trying to have a Puppy class derived from a specialize parent class, but without knowing which parent class it will inherit. And at the same time, give the Puppy class a set of abstract methods to implement.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class DogSkillSet(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def bark(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def chase(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def fetch(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Dog:
    def __new__(cls, race, **kwargs):
        if race == 'sheperd':
            return GermanSheperd()
        elif race == 'rott':
            return Rottweiller()


class GermanSheperd:
    def __init__(self):
        self.race = "sheperd"


class Rottweiller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.race = "rott"


class Puppy(Dog, DogSkillSet):
    def __init__(self, race):
        super().__init__(race)

    def bark(self):
        print("small woof")

    def chase(self):
        print("stare into the air")

    def fetch(self):
        print("stare into the air")

    def play(self):
        print('playing')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_dog = Puppy('berger')
    my_dog.bark()
```

But the inheritance doesn't happen after the specialization. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Because the class Puppy derived from Dog and not specifically from GermanSheperd or Rottweiller. When I try to instantiate a Puppy object, it create a Dog's __new__ method and return either the specialized object GermanSheperd or Rottweiller. And stop there, because it never arrive at the Puppy's __init__ method. And I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Dog.__new__` which is inherited by `Puppy`, returns instances of `GermanShepherd` or `Rottweiler`, neither of which inherit from `DogSkillSet` (or `Dog` for that matter)

Comment: Yes, because I don't know if my parent class will be GermanSheperd or Rottweiller. So I choose this approach to give the Puppy object either the GermanSheperd's behavior or the Rottweiller's. Should I create a DogInterface first?

Comment: @zass that is not what your code accomplishes though. In general, there is no sane way to make individual instances of some class inherit from different base classes. The sane way to do this is simply **not to use inheritance** and instead, use composition.

Comment: Alright I will try it that way. Thank you for your help.